# On Button click multiple images must change

Tags: slideshow

1. As shown in image that when we click on button1 or button2, set of images must be changed as follows with slideshow images.
2. I have a slider with thumbnails and buttons placed above the thumbnails as shown in image,  if we press the buttons all the thumbnail and slide images must change according to buttons

[image]

Comment: What software are you using, and what is your question?

Comment: Hi Sir, i am using html, css, javascript and jquery for building a website which contains fullscreen sliders with thumbnails and three options above the thumbnails to change images all over the silder.

Comment: There is still no question. Code fragments would help as well.

Comment: Why not just add "button-1", "button-2" and "button-3" classes to the images accordingly, and use `display:none` on the ones that are not the ones you want to view by default, and then use a .click() function to toggle which ones display and which don't?

Comment: show us some code or provide a fiddle

Comment: please visit the link given [link](http://newmet.comlu.com/) , there when advanced ticket are clicked all the thumbnail images and the slider images must change on clicking of buttons